# NetLogo: Creating Variable from Distance to Specific Patch

Tags: netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I have an issue in Netlogo giving agents the variable with distance (in patches) to a chosen patch that is water.
The agents are supposed to act according to their distance to water.
I want the agent to find the closest patch that has water = true, calculate the distance to that patch and save that specific distance in a variable that may change if the agent moves.

So the way I went about this is as follows:

```
turtles-own
[
next-river-patch
distance-to-river
]

to go
ask turtles
                                            ;find closest patch that has water = true
                                            ;calculate distance to that patch and save it in the turtles-own variable "distance-to-river"
    set next-river-patch (min-one-of patches in-radius 100 with [water = true] [distance myself])
    set distance-to-river distance next-river-patch
    
    
                                           ;check whether there is water in peception radius 
                                           ;and whether directed walk is initiated
    ifelse random-float 1 > water-directedness 
   and
    patches with [water = true] in-radius 300 = true

    [walk-directed]
    [walk-undirected]
    
    tick
    
end 


to walk-directed
                                            ;deviation of random normal is smaller, the further from next 1st order river and is raised by a high pioneering rate
                                            ;with half the distance of the perception radius of 300 resulting in a deviation of 45 degrees and 
                                            ;a pioneering rate of 0.5 leading to no influence onto the final deivation and a pioneering rate of 1 doubling the deviation. 
 let deviation 90 * ( 1 - distance-to-river / 300) * ( 2 * pioneering-along-rivers)
  
  face min-one-of patches with [ water  = true][distance myself]
   rt random-normal 0 (1 * deviation)
  fd 1
end

to walk-undirected
 ask turtles [
  
  rt random-normal 0 (2.25 * descision-randomness * 100)
    fd 1
    
                                            ;it turns into a cumulated normal direction (with the chance of moving straight ahead being highest) and the standard 
                                            ;deviation being defined by the descision-randomness-slider, with default being 45° and max being 225°
  ]
  
end
```

so the issue I am having is that the line

"set next-river-patch (min-one-of patches in-radius 100 with [water = true] [distance myself])"

returns a variable containing
the coordinates of the next patch that is water. Anyhow, i dont want the coordinates, but the distance to that patch so that i can use it in my cumulated direction.
set distance-to-river distance next-river-patch does not work.

Does anybody have an idea as to why that could be? I am relatively new to NetLogo so the answer may possibly seem very obvious.

Thank you very much!

P.S.: Another, possibly unrelated issue with my model is that agents turn dozens of times before each tick instead of each agent doing a single turn before going forward by 1.
So if you happen to see the solution to that by looking over the code, i would also be forever grateful.

Comment: Hi Tjaark, can you please provide a [mre]? Who reads your question should be able to blindly copy your code, paste it in their NetLogo, and, without the need for any modifications, run it to reproduce the exact problem you are describing. Thanks!

Comment: Hey Matteo, i will try! It might take me a while to construct it  though, i am sorry

Comment: Please keep in mind that for a querent already struggling with NetLogo, converting a model or extracting a piece of it so that it might run standalone would only create more challenges, introduce more bugs, and may be an insurmountable challange. If more details might help, ask, but asking a querent to produce an entirely new mini model seems a bit much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest problem first:

**Why are some turtles moving more than once per tick?**

`walk-undirected` is called by turtles, and it does `ask turtles`. So every turtle is making every turtle so the action. It should be like the other procedure and just do that action, no `ask`.

**patches ......  = true**

This is an error. You are comparing the agentset made by `patches with ...` to the boolean value `true`. An agentset can never be true OR false. An agentset can be empty, or have one or more agents in it. The `any?` reporter is used to determine if an agentset has **any** members.

**The main question**

It looks like you are already doing what you are asking. The line starting `set nearest-river-patch` gets the nearest water patch, and the line `set distance-to-river` calculates the distance to that patch. Not that if there is not any water in radius 100, next-river-patch will be `nobody`.

I don't see anything that would give you the coordinates (as a list?). Maybe try some parentheses to make sure the reporters are being evaluated in the right order:

```
set next-river-patch (min-one-of ((patches in-radius 100) with [water = true]) [distance myself])
```

You could also use `with-min`

```
set next-river-patch one-of ( ( ( patches in-radius 100 ) with [ water = true ] ) with-min [distance myself] )
```

Otherwise, correct the other errors and see what happens.

Comment: That was really helpful already, thank you very much!
I have implemented your corrections and they are working perfectly.
Except for the last one, it still shows me the patch instead of a number:
So distance-to-river is supposed to give me a variable containing a number (ranging from 0 to 300, depending on where my agent is, that specifies the distance to the next water patch within a radius of 300).
But it only gives me the coordinates of the next patch, and not the distance to it, so, e.g., "patch 962 607" instead of "93", which is the distance of my turtle to the given patch.